# Twitter API returns Link to tweet while tweet has no link

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I have a tweet in my timeline which has no link. When I retrieve my tweets via the twitter API it contains a link which refers to the tweet itself, e.g.:

```
"expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/i/web/status/<tweed-id>",
```

Is this intented behaivior?
I searched for this in the twitter API Docs but was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Tweet JSON and it contains the field `truncated: true` then you need to use the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter to retrieve the complete Tweet object.

Comment: Oh, interesting! That one tweet (with no link) has `truncated: true`. While all the other tweets (with links) have `truncated: false`. I'll investigate!

Comment: Thx a lot. Using `tweet_mode=extended` is the solution (for me)!